# Newbie user is confused

Tags: wallets

Bear with me. I bought at the ico. At some point thereafter, I set up a Galleon wallet and received my XTZ there. Late last year, I set up a web based tezos wallet on TezBox.com but it has a zero balance of XTZ. The two wallets have different addresses.

Now, I need to know what to do. I would like to just use the Tezbox wallet and address. But when I try to transfer XTZ from Galleon to my Tezbox wallet, There is an error on TZScan:

```
404
path [{kind:generic,error:Operation ooBQq2cSp2HmXkhAZvL9m3Dr9BCwvwmx2LmwCJn1dDHyuDYRKw9 rejected by the mempool pre filter}] not found
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Please accept the answer if your issue was resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are with two distinct wallets. One in Galleon, and the other one in TezBox. The error you are getting on transfer refers to using low fees. Raise the fee and it will work.

Comment: Note that when is the first time a new wallet receives a transfer, i.e., the address is not revealed yet, the network requires an specific fee for revelation. So, total fee must cover operations.

Comment: Thanks but I have tried with several amounts to cover he extra charges (all the way up to 1 XZ) and nothing works. You can see them here:  https://tzscan.io/tz1iBQKgqoxV9KEqWgQHTKti6PfgeKr6tkxa

Comment: Your gas limit is set to 120. It should be at least 10300.

Comment: You need to update your wallet to the latest version.

Comment: I have looked all over Galleon and there is no place that even mentions "Gas Limit."  Where can I change this?

Comment: Update your wallets to the latest versions. Old versions used less gasLimit and storageLimit values and may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Congratulations. Glad you could solve it.

Comment: @Tri please accept luiz’s answer. There is a checkmark sign below the voting icon please use that, thank you.